# How to refresh/reload/re-render/re-'init' a subclassed UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a subclass of UIView called `IncidentHeaderView` that I'm displaying within a parent view (it's actually re-used across a bunch of parent views which are navigated via a TabBarController).

`IncidentHeaderView` takes a couple of values from NSUserDefaults and displays them as labels. It works perfectly when the app is started, and displays the right information. The problem starts when the values in NSUserDefaults change during runtime and I need `IncidentHeaderView` to reflect those changes.

This is my subclassed UIView, `IncidentHeaderView`, which also has a simple .xib for layout:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class IncidentHeaderView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var incidentHeaderContentView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var incidentNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var incidentDateLabel: UILabel!

    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func commonInit() {

        println("incident header common init")

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("IncidentHeader", owner: self, options: nil)
        incidentHeaderContentView.frame = self.bounds
        incidentHeaderContentView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth
        self.addSubview(incidentHeaderContentView)

        if let var activeIncidentName = defaults.stringForKey("activeIncidentName") {
            incidentNameLabel.text = activeIncidentName.uppercaseString
        }

        if let var activeIncidentDate: AnyObject = defaults.stringForKey("activeIncidentDate") {
            incidentDateLabel.text = activeIncidentDate.uppercaseString
        }

    }

}
```

Ok, so the values within NSUserDefaults can be changed from other places within in the app.

The most common example is that I pop up a modal from the parent View that displays `IncidentHeaderView` and within this modal, I change the value of the relevant NSUserDefaults. When I dismiss the modal, I want `IncidentHeaderView` to re-render so that it displays the new label values from NSUserDefaults.

How do I do this in the most effective/efficient way?

I've tried calling setNeedsDisplay() on `IncidentHeaderView`. I've tried posting and observing notifications. No dice.

My only successful attempt has been to strip out a bunch of the init stuff from `IncidentHeaderView` and call it inside a function from the parent view's viewWillAppear method, but this seems really janky and not quite what I had in mind. In my head, I wanted to keep this functionality within the subclassed UIView:

```
 func updateIncidentHeaderView(incidentHeaderView: IncidentHeaderView) {

     if let var activeIncidentName = defaults.stringForKey("activeIncidentName") {
         incidentHeaderView.incidentNameLabel.text =  activeIncidentName.uppercaseString
     }

    if let var activeIncidentDate: AnyObject = defaults.stringForKey("activeIncidentDate") {
         incidentHeaderView.incidentDateLabel.text = activeIncidentDate.uppercaseString
     }
 }
```

So, can someone point me in the right direction for re-rendering/re-initing a subclassed view within a parent view?

Thanks.

Comment: try `setNeedsDisplay` this method calls `drawInRect` method

Comment: Tried that, although I may be calling in the wrong place/at the wrong time?

Comment: might be, where you want your view to be refreshed call that and tell me what is happening..

Comment: Ok, so in the parent view with contains `IncidentHeaderView`, I'm calling:  `incidentHeaderView.setNeedsDisplay()` inside of `viewWillAppear()`. This does nothing.

Comment: (Obviously, the parent view knows about this subview because it's wired up correctly via interface builder: `@IBOutlet weak var incidentHeaderView: IncidentHeaderView!`